# About a generalization of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

I've come upon [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61141/generalization-of-borsuk-ulam) MO post, and I was wondering if there is a way to generalize what is said in the answer at the very bottom. Specifically, we have that given continuous maps $f: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$, and $g: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, if $f$ is an involution, then there is a point $x \in \mathbb{S}^n$ such that $g(x) = g(f(x))$, i.e. the value at $x$ is fixed under the transformation of the sphere by $f$.

We know from the answer of the post that for a general $f$, there need not be such a fixed point. But now what if instead $f$ is such that there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $f^k$ is the identity map, do we still get such a fixed point? Furthermore, do we know about other spaces besides the sphere that have this property when $f$ is an involution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first observation is that a map $f:S^n\to S^n$ with $f^k=\operatorname{Id}_{S^n}$ generates a topological action of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/k$ on $S^n$. So we are talking about generalising from $\mathbb{Z}/2$ actions to $\mathbb{Z}/k$ actions.

There are many generalisations of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem of this kind in the literature. Most of them concern estimates of the dimension of the set
$$
A(g)=\{x\in S^n \mid g(x)=g(f^i(x))\mbox{ for }i=1,\ldots , k\},
$$ for various flavours of map $g:S^n\to M^m$.

Interpreted this way, the answer to your first question appears to be negative in general, by a theorem of Munkholm in

*Munkholm, H. J.*, On the Borsuk-Ulam theorem for (Z_{p^ a}) actions on (S^{2n-1}) and maps (S^{2n-1} \to R^ m), Osaka J. Math. 7, 451-456 (1970). [ZBL0211.55701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0211.55701).

In particular, let $k=p^a\neq 9$ be an odd prime power with $a>1$, and let $\omega=\operatorname{exp}(2\pi i/p^a)$ be a primitive $p^a$-th root of unity. Let $f:S^{2n-1}\to S^{2n-1}$ be given in complex coordinates by
$$
f(z_1,\ldots , z_n)=(\omega z_1,\ldots ,\omega z_n).
$$
Then Munkholm's "mod $p^a$ Borsuk-Ulam anti-theorem" seems to imply that there exists a continuous map $g:S^{2n-1}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$ with $A(g)=\emptyset$.

For a summary of positive results in the literature, you could do worse than Chapter 1 of [Yuri Turygin's thesis at the Unviersity of Florida](http://etd.fcla.edu/UF/UFE0020106/turygin_y.pdf).

Comment: This is interesting. But what if I don't want other powers of $f$ to fix the value, and just want $g(x)= g(f(x))$? We could still have $A(g)$ empty in this case, if for every $x$ some other power doesn't fix the value.

Comment: In particular, $g : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(\theta) = \cos(\theta)$, and $f:S^1 \to S^1$ such that $f(\theta) = \theta + 1/n$ for some natural $n$ large enough. The map $f$ is such that $f^n$ is the identity on $S^1$, and we should get $A(g)$ empty, but $g(S^1)$ and $g(f(S^1))$ have two points of intersections, so two such "fixed points".

Comment: Sorry, @Mark I forgot to ping you

Comment: @PaulCusson: You are right, I think, and your example above has $A(g)$ empty whilst having points for which $g(x)=g(f(x))$. (I suppose you meant to write $f(\theta)=\theta + 2\pi/n$ or something similar?) There doesn't seem to be much in the literature about your precise question.

Comment: About your second question, there has been some work done on extending Borsuk-Ulam to homology spheres, see the references in the linked thesis (Conner-Floyd, Munkholm,...)

Comment: PS I got pinged anyway, the author of any question or answer always gets notified of any comments on their post.

Comment: Yes I meant $+2\pi /n$. And thanks for clarifying about the ping, I wasn't sure how that worked exactly. By you are right, mean about my counterexample, right? Thanks for the input.